# Python: Handling a missing space from a filepath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, file-handling

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents\\Outlook Files\\test.pst")
```

This code is part of a function that adds the filepath to the "File name" field of a file browsing display.

My issue is that when the path is added the "Outlook Files" part is included without the space between the words 'Outlook' and 'Files', thus it returns as "Documents\OutlookFiles\test.pst"

Is there any way I can include the missing space when the filepath is added into the file name of the browsing display on my web app?

Comment: Try to use simple quote to define the string and use double quote inside the string to identify this complete folder. 'Documents\\"Outlook Files"\\test.pst'

Comment: Could you not just escape the space? `"Documents\\Outlook\ Files\\test.pst"`

Answer (score 0):

Different types of quotes and 'r' for raw string did not help with the space being deleted. Instead I had to resort to changing the file location to one without a space to solve the issue.